# I want to display a number in a textbox when a button is pressed

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to use the text property in the button property field. this is the code i have tried but it does not work.

```
private void btnOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
      String btnOneText = btnOne.getText( );
      txtDisplay.setText(btnOneText);
}
```

Comment: Just declaring a method named `btnOneActionPerformed` doesn't really accomplish much. Can you show us how you call this method? Can you show us how you create and initialize your button? The usual way to do this is to call the button's `addActionListener()` during setup to add an action listener that performs an action when the button is clicked. Check out the [official tutorial on buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) -- it is concise and well-written and contains good examples.

Comment: Insufficient code. Can you show us how you added ActionListener to your JButton?

Comment: Jason C - I right clicked on the button then Action then Action performed. i am trying to follow an online course which up to this point has seemed to work fine. ( http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_events.html )

Comment: Oh dear... drag-n-drop. Did you put any text in your button? Show us as much as possible.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read the oracle official tutorials that have good examples. [How to use Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

I made you an example of what you have to do.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TextFieldTest {

    private JPanel panel;

    public TextFieldTest(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        final JTextField textfield = new JTextField(10);
        final JButton button = new JButton("Press me");
        //here i add the action listener, that will listen the input event
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //this is anonymous class
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                String text = button.getText();
                textfield.setText(text);
            }
        });

        panel.add(textfield);
        panel.add(button);

    }

     /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Textfield example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLocationByPlatform(Boolean.TRUE);
        frame.add(new TextFieldTest().panel);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

See it's more simpler than using a gui-editor, then you understand what you do. It's better to do this first and later when you understand what you are doing use the netbeans gui-editor.

Comment: My Problem is i am not a comp programmer (obvious) but i have to show a laod og 14 year olds how to make a calculator and using a GUI (netbeans) seemed the best and easiest way